# UIPopOverController with UINavigationController with Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, xcode4.2

this may sound simple, but somehow I am not able to get out of this. I have created an empty app, added two tabBar items by creating them in AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m files. Now for my second tabBar item, when the user clicks the second tabBar item I want to display a popOverController. I have programmatically created that, by following this link [Link](http://mobileoverlord.com/displaying-a-uipopovercontroller-from-a-uitabbaritem/). Now my problem is I want to use Navigation Controller in my code where I have created my popOverController (AppDelegate.m) so that in my popOverController.m, I want to use the NavController to push other views. If someone has a simple way of achieving this, would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a subclass of the PopOverController, unless you are making your own UI for it.

Comment: Look at Apple's iPad Human Interface Guidelines documentation, it really should be perfectly adequate to achieve what you want. It seems trivial enough, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am little confused on where your problem is. What your trying to do is possible and should be straight forward. If your problem is that the Next view is not being pushed its because in popoverController you don't have access to `self.navigationController`. So easy solution, create a UINavigationController variable and pass navigationController to your popover or use notifications to pass what view to push back to your AppDelegate.

**EDIT**

You can use this to listen for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(popOverViewControllerSelected:) name:@"popOverViewSelectedViewToPush" object:someObjectTellingYouWhatViewToPush];
```

Then use this to send the notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"popOverViewSelectedViewToPush" object:@"ViewController1"];
```

The selector would be your function name (I just put a descriptive name "popOverViewControllerSelected") and the object would need to be information on what viewController to push (i.e. 1,2,3 or @"view1"). Then you would need:

```
- (void)popOverViewControllerSelected:(id)sentObject
{
     // If your passing an NSNumber could use a switch
                 switch ((int)sentObject) {
            case 0:
                //Push This view
                break;
            case 1:
                //Push that view
                break;
            case 2:
                //Push someother view
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

The other way I was talking about is in you popOverViewController.h add in

```
@interface .........
{
     UINavigationController *navController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;
```

In you popOverViewController.m add the:

```
@synthesize navController;
```

Then where ever you are adding the popOverViewController just add:

```
[popOverViewController setNavController:self.navigationController];
```

And now in your PopOverViewController you can call:

```
[navController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

But I recommend doing the first option.

Comment: Hi Jaybit, your solution seems convincing, can you please provide an example code for better understanding as I am novice to IOS.

Comment: I edited my post to have more information and code. The main idea here is getting access to the NavigationController. The first part is through notifications, the second is by passing the navigationController to the popover.